# Nested Python C Extensions/Modules?

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-api

How do I compile a C-Python module such that it is local to another? E.g. if I have a module named "bar" and another module named "mymodule", how do I compile "bar" so that it imported via "import mymodule.bar"?

(Sorry if this is poorly phrased, I wasn't sure what the proper term for it was.)

I tried the following in setup.py, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='mymodule',
      version='1.0',
      author='Me',
      ext_modules=[Extension('mymodule', ['mymodule-module.c']),
                   Extension('bar', ['bar-module.c'])])
```

**Edit**

Thanks Alex. So this is what I ended up using:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

PACKAGE_NAME = 'mymodule'

setup(name=PACKAGE_NAME,
      version='1.0',
      author='Me',
      packages=[PACKAGE_NAME],
      ext_package=PACKAGE_NAME
      ext_modules=[Extension('foo', ['mymodule-foo-module.c']),
                   Extension('bar', ['mymodule-bar-module.c'])])
```

with of course a folder named "mymodule" containing `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions are [here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-names-and-packages):

> Extension('foo', ['src/foo1.c',
> 'src/foo2.c'])
>
> describes an extension that lives in
> the root package, while
>
> Extension('pkg.foo', ['src/foo1.c',
> 'src/foo2.c'])
>
> describes the same extension in the
> pkg package. The source files and
> resulting object code are identical in
> both cases; the only difference is
> where in the filesystem (and therefore
> where in Python’s namespace hierarchy)
> the resulting extension lives.

Remember, a package is always a directory (or zipfile) containing a module `__init__`.  To create a module that's a package body, that module will be called `__init__` and live under the package's directory (or zipfile).  I've never done that in C; if it doesn't work to do it directly, name the module e.g. `_init` instead, and in `__init__.py` do `from _init import *` (one of the very few legitimate uses of `from ... import *`;-).