# Python C-ext namespace mixed with regular python submodules?

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import, python-c-extension

This question has some resemblance with:

[Nested Python C Extensions/Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681281/nested-python-c-extensions-modules)

Only with a slight twist. Here I'm not trying to mix two C-exts, but one C-ext and a regular python submodule instead.

Is there a way for a C-extension to share the module namespace between the symbols "module.so" and those present in a submodule?

My module structure looks like this:

```
facs/
    facs/
      __init__.py
      setup.py
      facs.so
      [*.c files]
      utils/
        __init__.py
        galaxy.py
```

If I remove "utils" from the hierarchy, I can import facs and see the `facs.so` methods:

```
>>> import facs
>>> dir(facs)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'build', 'query', 'remove']
```

But when I put the utils submodule back and try to import the different parts, one namespace seems to mask the other (`utils` masks the symbols exported by `facs.so`):

```
>>> import facs
>>> dir(facs)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> import facs.utils
>>> facs.utils.galaxy.rsync_genomes("phix")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'galaxy'
>>> from facs.utils import galaxy
>>> galaxy.rsync_genomes("phix")
'Hello world'
```

As you see, after `dir(facs)`, `build`, `query` and `remove` are gone and `galaxy`
does not get imported properly unless I do a `from facs.utils import galaxy` instead
of re-using the initial import statement and simply accessing via `facs.utils.galaxy.rsync_genomes()` directly.

To sum up, my intended use of this module would be to do:

```
>>> import facs
>>> dir(facs)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'build', 'query', 'remove'
, 'utils'] <--- (Directly accessible from "facs")
>>> facs.utils.galaxy.rsync_genomes("phix")
'Hello world'
```

The (currently under development) code is in:

https://github.com/brainstorm/facs/tree/develop

In case someone wants to try it out by themselves. I'm using virtualenvs and my $PYTHONPATH
seems correct:

```
/home/roman/.venvburrito/lib/python:
/home/roman/.virtualenvs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And the installation seems to be successful too:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facs-2.0dev-py2.7.egg/
(py27)$ ls
EGG-INFO  facs.py  facs.pyc  facs.so  utils/
```

It seems that no `__init__.py` file is actually copied to the top level directory but touching it there or not does not affect the importing behavior described above.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to rename `facs.so` to  something else? Try to use a different name for the package and the `.so`

Comment: The `.so` file is generated when the python module is compiled/installed, I don't generate it myself... sorry if that wasn't clear :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be carefull you are importing the so file first, and not the facs package. Are you running your python console over facs package source directory ?

Try to go outside the package directory and everything will make sense.

Also, next import doesn't say that all modules behind your facs directory will be imported:

```
>> import facs
>> dir (facs)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

You have to set your imports in each `__init__.py` file, for example if you want to export some simbols from your `.so` file when you `import facs`, you should have the following contents in your `__init__.py` file:

```
>> from _facs import function_name, function_name .....
```

And then, when you `import facs`, it will import those functions for you.

Take the same pattern for your sub-package utils.

I would also recommend to rename your `facs.so` file to `_facs.so` file to avoid name collisions between package name and module name.

Comment: Hello pfreixes! It's nice to see you over here! I actually put in place your suggestions, but that doesn't seem to fix my problem :_S: https://github.com/brainstorm/facs/commit/ffa1df9be3d8167c5d5ae4146bf4f8ae4273d8fe

Comment: After the commit above, I get "Import error: no module named facs", so I cannot load any of the symbols :-/ Again, thanks a lot for having a look at that! :D

Comment: Sorry but facs/__init__.py should be """from facs._facs import ...""" and it should be work ...

Comment: File "/home/roman/dev/facs/facs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    `from facs._facs import build, query, remove`
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_facs)

Comment: I've observed that the facs/__init__.py file I just edited, does not get copied to the .virtualenv dir: $ ls ~/.virtualenvs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facs-2.0dev-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/
EGG-INFO  _facs.py  _facs.pyc  _facs.so  utils .... but the result is the same, the module does not get imported at all (ImportError: No module named facs).

Comment: For the record, I'm trying the `import facs` from outside the repository itself (in $HOME to be more specific).

Comment: Getting closer: `SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly`there seems to be a problem with the `initfacs` function...

Comment: Solved!: https://github.com/brainstorm/facs/commit/44b72696a240bdc2a80cdfb2ad467fd18df6ce99 Thanks pfreixes!

Comment: When I use this exact same strategy, I get "No module named _facs". Argh, so frustrating.